# Can I travel to Bulgaria with an italian refugee travel document?

Tags: air-travel, refugees, bulgaria, italian-residents

I'm a holder of an Italian refugee passport (travel document) and an Italian residence permit and I need to travel to Sofia by next week, I have checked online about this matter, but I would like some assuring information before I travel if I need a visa or not?
Please if someone went through that experience please share with me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

TIMATIC states :

> ##### Visa Exemption

> Passengers with a residence permit issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 90 days.

Comment: So I won't need a Visa ?

Comment: You won't @Joeylink

Comment: Thanks brother, I appreciate your help :))